# how to automatically adjust serial number in jtable when delete on row form it

Tags: java, jtable

[image]

In a above table there are 4 value in table represented by Serial numbers (S.NO 
1,2,3,4)

[image]

The Problem is when we delete a row from a table like S.NO 2

[image]

Then it delete a row by using removeRow Method but it don't adjust the S.No
The Code For S.NO is like i introduce a int variable called tree and when ever we press add button it add one value in tree

```
int tree=0;
```

and when we press ADD button

```
tree++;
```

And i also try

```
.getRowCount()
```

to get row number it get it and print it also but then again when we delete a row and add another row it just print that row number.So how to adjust S.No

Code of Add Button(use to add data on table and also in Data Base)

```
class google{ 

int tree=0;   

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  //add Button method       

model=(DefaultTableModel) mtt.getModel();  //mtt name of table

tree++; //increment S.No 

 model.addRow(new Object[]{tree,proname.getText(),TFroo.getText(),qty.getText(),total.getText(),bn.getText()});  // getting text from text field and add it in table 

 // and some other code to add data on  database 

}//Add Button ActionPerformed

}//google
```

Code of delete Button

```
 int p= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE ?","CONFORM",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if(p==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
 model.removeRow(mtt.getSelectedRow());
 // and some other code to delete data also form database 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(p==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    int row = mtt.getSelectedRows()[0];// returns row position(Here mtt is  name of table)
    model.removeRow(row);  
    for(int index=row ;index<model.getRowCount();index++){
        model.setValueAt(index+1, index, 0); //setValueAt(data,row,column)
    }
}
```

Comment: Automatically adjust serial number when delete row from jtable without duplicate serial numbers

Answer (score 0):

Just re-setting the value of the deleted row incrementally

```
if(p==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    int row = mtt.getSelectedRows()[0];// returns row position
     model.removeRow(row);

       for(int y=row ;y<model.getRowCount();y++){

          model.setValueAt(y, y, 0); //setValueAt(data,row,column)
       }

}
```

Comment: i add code of Add Button And Delete Button take a look